# Импортирование *.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, smali, so

У меня есть Android приложение и там имеются файлы (.so), только вот я не имею исходного кода этого приложения, но я хочу добавить туда свой .so файл и чтобы он взаимодействовал с другими. Я декомпилировал это приложение, закинул туда свой .so файл к другим, но мой файл просто не загружается. Я делаю что то не так? Я скомпилировал свой .so файл с помощью Android NDK. Пробовал загрузить свою библиотеку с помощью этого в MainActivity.smali:

```
const-string v0, "test"
invoke-static {v0}, Ljava/lang/System;->loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Но библиотека не загружается и действий также 0.
В этой сфере я чайник.

Comment: Приложение вылетает? - смотрите логи. Не выполняется код библиотеки? - а где вы его вызываете? Я как-то не помню, да и не задавался вопросом - вызывает ли Андроид какую-то точку входа при загрузке библиотеки, обычно её связывают с java кодом с помощью JNI и дёргают нужные функции нативными java-методами. И неясно в какой метод `MainActivity` вы вписали этот код загрузки.

Comment: Библиотека не загружается, поскольку код на C/C++ не вызывается из кода Java (без изменения исходного кода приложения не обойтись).

Comment: Спасибо большое ребятам сверху! Я разобрался.